# List comprehension in nested lists Python

Tags: python, list, nested

```
dev_a = [[True, 1, 2, 3], [False, 1, 2, 3], [True, 1, 2, 3]]

dev_b = []
```

My goal is to iterate over nested lists in `dev_a` and check if `[0]` is `True` or `False`. I need the nested list in `dev_b`, when `[0]` is `False`.

My approach was the following:

```
if (x[0] for x in dev_a) is False:
   ?
```

I don't know what to tell the machine, that it will copy the whole dataset.

I need it like this, when it's done:

```
dev_a = [[True, 1, 2, 3], [False, 1, 2, 3], [True, 1, 2, 3]]

dev_b = [False, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `[x for x in dev_a if not x[0]]`

Answer (score 1):

what you want is this:

```py
dev_a = [[True, 1, 2, 3], [False, 1, 2, 3], [True, 1, 2, 3]]

dev_b = [x for x in dev_a if x[0] == False]
```

take note though, this will be dynamic depending on your input. So you could end up with a single array, or multiple.

Answer (score 0):

```
for sublist in dev_a:
    if not sublist[0]:
        dev_b.append(sublist)
```

Something like this?

If you want dev_b to be a flat list, use extend

```
for sublist in dev_a:
    if not sublist[0]:
        dev_b.extend(sublist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `filter`

```
dev_a = [[True, 1, 2, 3], [False, 1, 2, 3], [True, 1, 2, 3]]

dev_b = list(filter(lambda l: l[0] is False, dev_a))

print(dev_b)
```

Result:

```
[[False, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Use `next()` instead of `list()` if you want just one result instead of a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dev_a = [[True, 1, 2, 3], [False, 1, 2, 3], [True, 1, 2, 3]]
dev_b = [e for e in dev_a if e[0] is False]
print(dev_b)
```

output

```
[[False, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flattened list

```py
# filter only the inner items you want using filter function
outer = list(filter(lambda a: a[0] == False, dev_a))
# or without using filter
outer = [a for a in dev_a if not a[0]]

# flatten all items
x = [item for inner in outer for item in inner]
```

Result:

```py
[False, 1, 2, 3]
```